# Strange error when resetting dynamically changing jQuery-mobile-Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm currently working on a webapp for which I'm using jQuery-Mobile. I pull data in a update-ui-function (time and length of a track) from a server and use them to display the current position in a music-track (time beeing the slider's value, length beeing it's max). This is working fine.

It gets strange though if the user jumps to a previous track. You would expect, that since the update-ui-function runs every second the slider gets completely reset. This however is not the case. It jumps back a bit, but not to the very end and doesn't get updated afterwards.
Since a picture is worth a hundred words:

The slider if it is working correct

[image: The slider if it is working correct]

The slider after the user jumps to a previous track

[image: The slider after the user jumped]

So again: My problem is that the slider isn't reset and it stops moving, even though the update-ui-function does update two time-displays correctly.

Here is how the slider gets updated:

```
//Get the current position (time)
$(this).find("time").each(function(){
    time = $(this).text();
});

//And the total length (time)
$(this).find("length").each(function(){
    length = $(this).text();
});

//Set slider and ps
$("#positionSlider").attr("max", length);
$("#positionSlider").attr("value", Number(time)).slider("refresh");

//The time-displays which are updatet correctly
$("#currentTime").text(format_time(time));
$("#totalTime").text(format_time(length));
```

I tried resetting the max- and value-attribute before the update, but this only led to the fact, that the slider stop working completely. Removing the slider and reappending it to my DOM screwed up my css.

Any help or idea is appreciated.

EDIT: HTML-Markup

```
<div id="position">
    <input id="positionSlider" class="ui-hidden-accessible" type="range" name="slider-mini" id="slider-mini" value="0" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true" data-mini="true" />
    <p id="currentTime">00:00:00</p><p id="totalTime">00:00:00</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML markup? Also, use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: `$("#positionSlider").attr("value", Number(time)).slider("refresh");` to this `$("#positionSlider").val(Number(time)).slider("refresh");` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/MrbYR/

Comment: @MelanciaUK: See above, also what is the difference between ´attr()´ and `prop()` @Omar: Thanks - that worked. Leaves me confused, but it's working.

Comment: you're welcome :) http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.attr('value', value)` use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), and then call `refresh` method.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/MrbYR/)**

```
$("#positionSlider").val(value).slider("refresh");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`:

> Attributes vs. Properties
>
> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes. For example, selectedIndex, tagName,
>   nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected
>   should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery
>   1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr. These do not have corresponding
>   attributes and are only properties.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/prop/